# A place for short questions and small ideas/suggestions?

Tags: discussion

While traversing the site, I had, on numerous occasions, an urge to share an idea, or to ask a short question that's not worth enough to make a separate post out of it. I know this is what *meta* is supposed to be used for, but I feel bad for polluting the main stream. Most of the time I need a comment or two to figure out whether it's stupid, or an idea people like. Hence, the suggestion:

`Should we have a post here on meta for sharing of short ideas, requests for clarification or just some observations?`

The answers should be itself formulated as questions, and people would express opinion in the comments. If a person gets a satisfying answer (regardless good or bad), he could just delete the post and take further action (e.g. write a proper question, or forget about the whole thing).

A good rule of thumb would be that if it's more than a few sentences long, or the answer you're expecting could be, it's probably better to make an ordinary question out of it.

Comment: Please **vote down** bad ideas, but do drop a comment. You can start by downvoting this particular question :)

Comment: Voting down an idea because you disagree with it is good with the [feature-request] tag, but is bad with the [discussion] tag.

Comment: What is the required rep to post multiple links and to include pictures?

Answer (score 2):

[The chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place for small ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Shall we have promote posts we think are important (mostly CW questions, probably --- e.g. those about LaTeX editors, why-do-you-use-LaTeX, collections of external resources) that could be easily visible by all, especially new visitors? Not sticking them to the top of the stream forum-style, but maybe having a special tag and make them prominent on the side somewhere near the top.

Comment: How about linking to them in the faq? (Can the mods change the faq?)

Comment: I don't think so, no. Sorry.

Comment: @Joseph: That was an answer to my second question?

Comment: Answer was to 'can we edit the FAQ': we can't.

Comment: Having them in FAQ is fine, but you know people --- most of them will probably first ask, and then bother reading the FAQ or searching through the existing answers. If they are existing users, they wouldn't need to see these featured questions. It's for the new members.